# Error with any Dropbox API calls (node.js) — "Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.dropboxapi.com:443"

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-sdk-js

I am attempting to set up Dropbox on my server side using Node.js. I have used the official documentation to write the very basic code to do this, with an access token generated from dropbox.com (just until I get this working). The code I used is shown below and is a variant on the code at http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/index.html .

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Dropbox = require('dropbox');
router.post('/testDropbox', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.dbxAccessToken);
  var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: req.body.dbxAccessToken});
  console.log(dbx);
  dbx.filesListFolder({ path: ''})
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      res.send(repsonse);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    })
  });
```

This caught error reads **"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.dropboxapi.com:443"**.

I am releatively new to Node.js so I hope it something simple I have missed perhaps in the set up.
Also, I am behind a proxy that uses NTLM and seeing an error with "443" in it does ring some alarm bells in my head.

Comment: Check my answer I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your proxy may be blocking calls**

If you can bypass the proxy, try this to see if the proxy is causing the issue.
Unfortunately, many corporations don't allow one to bypass a proxy so you may need to speak to someone in charge of such things to try and help.

**The workaround I use**

I now use a WiFi dongle connected to an external router to bypass the proxy. My code, as shown in the question, works as expected and with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
EAI_AGAIN
    The name server returned a temporary failure indication.  Try again later.
```

There is any server side error or problem with your dns.

**@edit:
There is a ssl cert problem on api.dropboxapi.com.** You can disable ssl checking by add on the top of your code after `use 'use strict';`:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Comment: I have added this line as you instructed and unfortunately the error is still there as it was before. Do you think perhaps that my proxy could be blocking as there is no valid SSL ceritifcate?

Comment: Yes. Please try without proxy.

Comment: I shall do when I get home. I am forced to use a proxy for my work so really the solution needs to work with a proxy. Do you think such a solution exists?

Comment: Yes, it works without a proxy; you were correct about that. Do you think there is a way I can get this to work through the proxy? (I have no control of the proxy)

Comment: You must check what is an error with proxy. Paste it here.

Comment: "Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.dropboxapi.com:443" is the only error I could obtain, I discovered the corporate proxy was blocking Dropbox requests. Fortunately I was allowed to bypass the proxy for a time which enabled me to get everything working.